# Determine Direction of Angular Material Tooltip to Apply Arrow

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, tooltip

I'm working in an Angular v10 project, using Angular Material. I'm wanting to write styling for mat-tooltip to give it an arrow pointing to the content that triggers the tooltip.

This is what I have right now:

[image]

I achieved this by adding the following styles:

```
.mat-tooltip.ds-tooltip {
    overflow: visible;

    &::before {
        content     : '';
        display     : block;
        position    : absolute;
        bottom      : 100%;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
        border-width: 12px;
        left        : calc(50% - 12px);
    }
}
```

However, this will only work when the tooltip is below the content, it the tooltip is applied in any other direction, it will still have a arrow at the top:

[image]

The arrow should now be pointing down.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do with Material? I suppose I would need to determine which direction a tooltip is placed in and then somehow apply different stylings accordingly, is there a way to do that?

Comment: I suggest to add custom class depending on your tooltip position, and then make your magic with css for each possible case.

Comment: I'm sorry @YoanAsdrubalQuintanaRamírez but I can't do that if I'm not able to determine the position of the tooltip, which is the primary question here.

Comment: ok, I'll try to show an example on stackblizt of what I means. for a while, you can evaluate to update your versions, the last version of material allow to specify custom classes to matTooltips

Comment: @YoanAsdrubalQuintanaRamírez thanks for the suggestion on updating. You're right, updating to at least v12 would give us class names with positions. However, since our project is used by several others, it's important we all stay on the same angular version. So we have to stay on v10 for now. v12 is when material starts using classes with position names.
My team has decided this feature won't be easy until all apps can update, so it's been put in backlog.

Comment: I think you can try the approach of make your custom tooltips, and use  Input to pass your custom classes. Please check this link https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/building-tooltips-for-angular-3cdaac16d138 with an example and I hope its help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview#positioning), depending on the position applied to tooltip different classes will be applied: `mat-tooltip-panel-above`, `mat-tooltip-panel-below`, mat-tooltip-panel-left, `mat-tooltip-panel-right`.

So, basically you need to specify styling per parent class of the parent container:

```
.mat-tooltip-panel-below {
  .mat-tooltip.ds-tooltip {
    overflow: visible;
  
    &::before {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 100%;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
      border-width: 12px;
      left: calc(50% - 12px);
    }
  }
}

.mat-tooltip-panel-above {
  .mat-tooltip.ds-tooltip {
    overflow: visible;
  
    &::before {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black transparent transparent  transparent;
      border-width: 12px;
      left: calc(50% - 12px);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution for apps on Angular 12+, unfortunately my app is on v10 and since it's a dependency of many other apps, it cannot be updated at this time

Answer (score 0):

Here is the only way it worked for me

**In css :**

```
.mat-tooltip {
  position: absolute;

  &::after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 0.5rem solid transparent;
    border-right: 0.5rem solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0.5rem solid #767676;
  }
  &.below {
    overflow: initial;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    &:after {
      top: -0.5rem;
      right: calc(50% - 0.5rem);
      transform: rotate(0);
    }
  }

  &.above {
    overflow: initial;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    &:after {
      bottom: -0.5rem;
      right: calc(50% - 0.5rem);
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
  }

  &.right {
    overflow: initial;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    &:after {
      left: -0.75rem;
      top: calc(50% - 0.25rem);
      transform: rotate(270deg);
    }
  }

  &.left {
    overflow: initial;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    &:after {
      right: -0.75rem;
      top: calc(50% - 0.25rem);
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
  }
}
```

**In html :**

```
matTooltipPosition="above" matTooltipClass="above"
```

or

```
matTooltipPosition="below" matTooltipClass="below"
```

or

```
matTooltipPosition="left" matTooltipClass="left"
```

or

```
matTooltipPosition="right" matTooltipClass="right"
```